# Create tar files from shell script with current time stamp

Tags: shell, quoting, filenames

I am trying to create a shell script which will back up my git codebase and save in a specific back up directory with current days name

So far I have :

```
#!/bin/bash

branch="master"

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
  then
    branch=$1
fi

workspace="~/GIT_Workspace/my_project/"
timestamp=$(date +%d_%b_%Y)
filename="~/GIT_Workspace/Back/$timestamp-$branch.tar.gz"

echo "*** Updating branch: $branch ***"
#git -C "$workspace" checkout "$branch"
#git -C "$workspace" fetch origin
#git -C "$workspace" pull origin "$branch"

echo "*** Saving to file $filename"
tar -zcvf "$filename" "$workspace"
```

Am not able to create the tar file and it always fails with below error :

`tar: Failed to open '~/GIT_Workspace/Back/10_Mar_2015-master.tar.gz'`

Any help ?

Comment: Quick sanity check: does the "Back" directory exist?

Comment: @JosephR. yes it does exist. I have been saving to this folder all this file, thought of writing a script to save some time.

Comment: Does `~/GIT_Workspace/Back` actually exist?? More importantly, it seems like you are trying to create the tar file inside the directory which you are trying to include in the tar file. That will lead to undefined behaviour which could be anything from infinite recursion to a portion of the tar file being included inside itself, possibly recursively to a certain number of levels. You need to create the tar file somewhere else!

Comment: Oh, the actual problem is that `~` is not being expanded to your home directory because you quoted the `~`. It's trying to open a file that literally begins with `~`. But see my other comment concerning the more important problem.

Comment: @Celada Ah silly mistake. `~` tilde was not getting expanded, i replaced it with complete path and works fine now. If you post this as an answer I will gladly accept it. Thanks for your help. When I get time, I will update script so that it picks up the Home directory path, but this works for now.

Comment: Never mind my comment about creating the tar file inside the directory that you are trying to archive. I reread your script and you are **not** actually doing that. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following lines,

```
workspace="~/GIT_Workspace/my_project/"
filename="~/GIT_Workspace/Back/$timestamp-$branch.tar.gz"
```

`~` is not getting expanded to your home directory because it's inside quotes. It needs to be outside of quotes in order to get expanded. So your script is trying to open a file that begins with a literal `~` character, which of course does not exist.

Options:

- `variable="$HOME/GIT_Workspace"`. We often avoid use of `~` altogether in scripts and use `$HOME` instead for no good reason other than that tilde expansion is generally considered an interactive feature best not used non-interactively. (Bad reason, but there you are...)
- `variable=~/GIT_Workspace` with no quoting at all. However we usually try to use quoting very diligently in scripts as opposed to in interactive usage because you never know when someone is going to come along and supply an argument or parameter with a space in it and then the quoting is required. Program defensively.
- `variable=~"/GIT_Workspace" with the`~` outside the quotes looks very odd but will work.

I recommend the first option.

Other comments:

- Your script does not seem to use any bashisms, so it might as well run under portable `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`. I encourage you to change the shebang line and in general to write scripts for `/bin/sh` unless you can *really* take advantage of some bashism.
- If you use ISO 8601 format for dates (`%Y-%m-%d`) then they will naturally be sorted in chronological order and also be free of natural language dependencies. I encourage you do do that too.
- You might consider backing up git repositories using `git` instead of `tar`. You can push to a bare repository that you keep for the purpose. You can push all branches and the reflog will keep history too in case of mistakes.